# How to mock component instance event

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine, material-dialog, ts-mockito

I want to test an event (`dialogEvent`) which is being triggered from a [material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) instance with [ts-mockito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito):

```
myFunc() {
    this.matDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent);

    this.matDialogRef.componentInstance.dialogEvent.subscribe(() => {
        this.doSomething();
    });
}
```

How can I spy on or mock it in my test?

```
it('should call doSomething() on dialogEvent', () => {
    // trigger DialogComponent.dialogEvent event here
    expect(comp.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```